# Remove duplicates for 2d array Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

I have an 2d array. When I'm adding more values to the array, some values are duplicates. How can I remove these? My aray, named a: looks like this:

```
[[u'82', <a href="/12222/">Button</a>], [u'67', <a href="/12333/">Button</a>], [u'23', <a href="/12344/">Button</a>], [u'19', <a href="/12345/">Button</a>], [u'23', <a href="/12344/">Button</a>]]
```

I have tried

```
import numpy as np
def unique(a):
    order = np.lexsort(a.T)
    a = a[order]
    diff = np.diff(a, axis=0)
    ui = np.ones(len(a), 'bool')
    ui[1:] = (diff != 0).any(axis=1) 
    return a[ui]
```

And

```
[list(t) for t in set(tuple(element) for element in a)]
```

And

```
from pandas import *
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 3], [1, 1], [5, 4], [2, 3]])
DataFrame(a).drop_duplicates().values
```

But none of them work. How can i delete duplicates from the 2d array?

Comment: I see no duplicates in your `a`, `drop_duplicates(subset='a')` should've worked

Comment: @EdChum, yes, but the dataframe must first be created before it can be referenced as a subset.  The OP was trying to do this all in one step, which is why it failed.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are trying to do everything in one step.  You need to break it up (EdChum was almost there)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=a)
```

Per EdChum's comment, this will not work unless the dataframe (df) has been created, otherwise we cannot reference it as the subset.

Comment: the chained call should've worked, there is no semantic difference between having the calls as separate function calls as opposed to chaining them

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected.  I guess I was thinking of a reference to "a" as the subset.  However, I just tried the chained call (not referencing a subset) as the OP suggested and it worked with no problem.

Comment: Now my code is:      import pandas as pd
import numpy as np                                                                                             a = np.array(list)
    #DataFrame(a).drop_duplicates().values

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=a)

Comment: And i get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapefolk.py", line 114, in <module>
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=a)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3138, in drop_duplicates
    duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, keep=keep)And i get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapefolk.py", line 114, in <module>
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=a)... @tnknepp